# Redirecting stdout to stderr in Python's subprocess/Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stderr

The subprocess module says that you can pass `STDOUT` to the `stderr` argument to get the standard error redirected to the standard out file handle.  However, there is no `STDERR` constant.  Is there a way to go the other way?  I want everything on stderr and stdout to be redirected to the stderr of the parent process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass in any file descriptor or file object. So use `sys.stderr`.